# Determining sea surface salinity with multisprectral satellite imagery

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, sentinel-2, multi-band

Could anyone with knowledge of remote sensing tell me if multispectral satellite imagery such as Landsat 8 or Sentinel 2 can be used to determine salinity differences in ocean surface water?
My research on the topic online did not yield much information.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps consider spectral mixture analysis. It involves decomposing the spectral signature of the water into its constituent parts, such as pure water, pure salt, and other materials that may be present.

Here is a journal that might be useful:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0303243419301217